# The meaning of the frequency in continuous signals

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-analysis

Suppose that for a given signal $x:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ both of the following Fourier identities hold.

$$ \hat{x}(\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R} x(t)e^{-it\omega} dt~~~,~~~x(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \hat{x}(\omega)e^{it\omega} d\omega$$

What **mathematical and physica**l interpretations    of the  the number $ \hat{x}(\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R} x(t)e^{-it\omega} dt$ do correspond  to the signal $x(t)$? Note that if we change the function $\hat{x}$ even in countably many points, then $x(t)$ will be unchanged.